# Step Function Not Executing In JS, But Is In MJS Node 18.x+

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Does anyone have a clue why this bit of code here:

```
import { SFNClient, StartExecutionCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sfn";

export const handler = async(event) => {
    
    const ev = {
  "txid": "8787878787877v423-98vh349hv34878787878787879",
  "sid": "8ac36b76-e102-5e1b-ad94-5bb5e6564956",
  "val": "80.0",
  "cur": "USD",
  "type": "s"
}
    
    const stepFunctions = new SFNClient({region: 'us-east-1'});
            let params = { input: JSON.stringify(ev), stateMachineArn: 'arn:aws:states:us-east-1:xxxxx'};
            const command = new StartExecutionCommand(params);
            
            await stepFunctions.send(command)
            .then((result) => console.log(result))
            .catch((er) => console.error(er.stack))
         
};
```

Executes the step function perfectly, however THIS code (included in a regular JS file also running node 18.x times out? [10 seconds+])

```
const { SFNClient, StartExecutionCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-sfn");

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const ev = {
  "txid": "8787878787877v423-98vh349hv34878787878787879",
  "sid": "8ac36b76-e102-5e1b-ad94-5bb5e6564956",
  "val": "80.0",
  "cur": "USD",
  "type": "s"
}

 let params = { input: JSON.stringify(ev), stateMachineArn: 'arn:aws:states:us-east-1:us-east-1:xxxxx'};
            
const command = new StartExecutionCommand(params);
            
            await stepFunctions.send(command)
            .then((result) => console.log(result))
            .catch((er) => console.error(er.stack))
}
```

Both lambda functions have adequate permissions and, although the latter code snippet is apart of a larger function, all prior code executes properly within just seconds.

I'm at a complete loss and have spent all day trying to figure out why this is happening.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is wrong here in both solutions. But I cannot say why it works in the first and in the second not.

```
await stepFunctions.send(command)
.then((result) => console.log(result))
.catch((er) => console.error(er.stack))
```

Try writing it like

```
try {
  const result = await stepFunctions.send(command);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

You should either `await` the promise, or in a non async function use the `then` and `catch` callbacks

Comment: tried this, didn't change the outcome